# Using SharedPreferences for caching

Tags: java, android, caching

For our client-server application, we use a framework that returns ready-made models from which we can get all the data. Now the task is to cache the latest information and reproduce it when the application loads until a response is received from the server. Using RealmDB is pointless, since it requires a model that will inherit its class.

How smart is it to use Sharedpreferences to cache the server's response to a specific request and simply reproduce the response?

Comment: You could try saving the key as the request url and the value as the Json response. Before making a call to the api, check does the api call exist as a key in the SP and return that instead otherwise continue with the call to the network. You'd need to think about the response being old and having to update it with a new call and save that response. But all in all, SP wouldn't be a bad solution.

Comment: @SmiffyKmc yes, that's how we use key-value pairs. I just heard that Sharedpreferences are slower than databases and with a large number of cached queries, serious problems can arise.

Comment: Well, shared preferences are to share preferences. Not for local caching. You *can* do it. But if you need a shared cache (aka shared preferences), you might want to take a look at JCS (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/). The LRU Memory Cache implementation is really fast.